# AJAX requests waiting for each other even though they are async?

Tags: jquery, ajax

It seems my AJAX requests are waiting for each other without any reason. I make them all async, so in fact this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: e.action,
    data: GetFilterData(),
    type: "POST"
}).done(function (data) {
    // Do Something
}
```

When I fire it 3 times my actions are different, so: The first time need `100ms`, the second `5ms` and the third `5ms`. In the network tab I see that the second is coming back after `105ms`, not `5`, and the third after `110ms` not `5ms`.

So it seems my async calls are handled in some kind of a queue system in MVC on the server side and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you post the whole code block. Just seeing the request itself isn't very useful.

Comment: Please provide the full code how you are calling in multi times..

Comment: Also add which server side technology you are using since some of them only serve one request at the time for a each user. For example ASP.NET does this if you have session state enabled.